# Why is there still a /etc/init.d in debian 8?

Tags: debian, systemd

I recently upgraded a couple of virtual hosts to debian 8. Now playing with them i found, that:

1. there is still a `/etc/init.d`, `/etc/rc0.d`, ... director with plenty of files in it (e.g. `/etc/rc2.d/S04ssh`)
2. there is a `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`, too
3. I have got an `/etc/init.d/apache2` script but no `apache2.service` file
4. nevertheless systemd seems to work. `systemctl start/stop apache2` works and my own written service file works, too.

So the question(s): Is something wrong here? Did I miss something important while upgrading? If not, how is this expected to work? (What exactly does systemd do with this mess?)

UPDATE: I found this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts which answers most part of my question. (Is this a duplicate question now?)

*What I'm still missing: Is it OK that jessie doesn't have an apache2.service file?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debian developers provide `sysvinit` script for fallback.

You can look it up at the [Transition plan to systemd by default](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/02/msg00013.html):

> a) Providing a fallback boot entry for sysvinit when systemd is the
>      default init in grub (#757298)
>
> b) Developing a mechanism to warn on inittab configurations which
>      are unsupported in systemd. (#761063)
>
> c) Providing documentation on how to remain with sysvinit on
>      upgrades and switch to sysvinit upon installation.

Also (I did not do any research if that is the case for Debian in particular) some systemd unit file are just wrappers around init scripts.